# How to select multiple values against single record in a column in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-aggregation

I have two tables with many to many relation.

table 1:

```
    Code    |  Product | 
------------+----------+
 00001      | product1 | 
 00002      | product2 |
```

table 2:

```
Tag_id |  name | 
-------+--------
1      | tag1  | 
2      | tag2  |
```

associated Table:

```
Tag_id  | Product_id 
--------+----------+
 1      | product1 | 
 1      | product2 | 
 1      | product3 | 
 2      | product4 |
 3      | product4 | 
 4      | product4 |
```

Someone please tell me how can i genrate table
like display below:

```
  Code      |  Product | Tags 
------------+----------+---------------
 00001      | product1 | tag1,tag2
 00002      | product2 | tag1,tag3,tag4
```

Or tags in a multiple columns.

Comment: Its better to get record for each tag id separately in your result table.

Comment: I also want it, So please tell me how can i do it?

Comment: Which dbms are you really using? Don't tag product not involved...

Comment: Postgresql....!

Comment: So remove the other dbms tags. And excuse the poor people who answered your question but for other dbms products.

Answer (score 0):

for mysql
Try this

```
select Code,Product,Group_concat(name) from table1 
left join associatedTable on table1.product=associatedTable.product_id 
left join table2 on table2.tag_id=associatedTable.tag_id
```

Comment: Which dbms is this for?

Comment: PostgreSQL does not have a `group_concat` function, and the OP has noted in comments that they are using PostgreSQL.